# Validation for dynamic radio buttons

Tags: python, django

I want to know how to check if a radio button has been selected before the user clicks submit. At the moment it allows a submission if nothing has been selected.

remove.html

```
{%for laptop in laptops%}
    <form action = "{%url 'laptops:delete'%}" method = "post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="radio">
  <input type="radio" id = "laptop_{{laptop.id}}" name="laptopname" value = "{{laptop.id}}">
            <label for = "laptop_{{laptop.id}}">{{laptop}}</label>
</div>
{%endfor%}
<input type="submit" value="Submit" id="delete-button"/>
    </form>
```

views.py

```
#Gets id value from the 'laptopname' radio button
laptopid = int(request.POST.get('laptopname'))
#Finds matching id value
laptop = Laptop.objects.get(id=laptopid)
#Populates form with matching data
data = {'Name': laptop.Name, 'specification': laptop.specification,'warranty': laptop.warranty,
    'condition':laptop.condition}
form = forms.MakeSale(initial=data)
return render(request, 'laptops/laptop_sale.html', {'form': form})
```

Is my approach wrong? Should I be doing the validation using a form for the radio buttons instead?

Comment: use javascript to validate the form before submit in front end, or check the value of the form after backend receives the http post, if failed, return 'error message' back to front end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(jQuery but the logic shouldd apply)

The way I did it was making an event wenn the user clicks the radio button to give me the id of that specific radio button. With the id you know witch radio button the user pressed.

```js
$("input").click(function () {
   alert($(this).attr("id"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Demo</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>

<input id="1" type="radio" name="lala">
<input id="2" type="radio" name="lala">
<input id="3" type="radio" name="lala">


<script  type="text/javascript" src="Demo.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

EDIT: if you just want to be sure the user clicks a radio button just add required at the end

```
<input id="3" type="radio" name="lala" required>
```

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for, but still a step in the right direction.